# Pagination - checking for existence of next/previous record

Tags: php, mysql, image, pagination, pdo

I have to do a photo paginate.

> << Previous  [PHOTO]   Next >>

Suposs that the actual page is something like that: `www.myWebSite.com/photo.php?id=12`

And if I press `Next`, then I'll redirected to `www.myWebsite.com/photo.php?id=13`, but if the photo with `id=13` was eliminated from the database, What I can do?

For example:

```
<?php

require_once '../classes/dataBaseManager/ImageDataBaseManagr.php';

if ( isset ( $_GET ['id'] ) ) {
  $id = $_GET ['id'];
  /**
  * Initialize my data base class.
  */
  try {
    $dataBase = ImageDataBaseManager::connect();
    $select = $dataBase->select( array ( 'id' => $id );
    $previous = (int)($select ['id'] - 1);
    $next = (int)($select ['id'] + 1);
    $photo = $select ['path'];
    echo '<a href="http://www.myWebSite.com/photo.php?id='.$previous.'">Previous</a>';
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'" />';
    echo '<a href="http://www.myWebSite.com/photo.php?id='.$next.'">Previous</a>';
  }
  catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    error_log( $e->getMessage );
    return;
  } 
}
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see your query here, but in your query you put `... WHERE photo_id >= 13 ORDER BY photo_id LIMIT 12`. That way, it starts at 13 if it's there, otherwise, it starts at the next highest, and grabs the next 12 records.

Comment: The only possible order would be by id descending?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is the flaw of implementation.
I will recommend following querystring (for next)

```
 photo.php?currentid=1&action=next
```

This way your select call will become something like mentioned by castor

Answer (score 0):

You have current page id and you want to get next existing ID. So construct query like:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `id` > \"$current_id\" ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

This should solve your problem.

When searching for previous photo use this query:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `id` < \"$current_id\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

You also need to check whether `mysql_num_rows()` is bigger than 0. If yes, you have next record. If no, you reached the last.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the maximum number of photos in your database and if the maximum is reached, don't show the `next` link.
Additionally you shouldn't do pagination with the id of the photo. Check the `LIMIT` option for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your site works. Do you want to let people know the image has been deleted? Or silently skip it? If you want to skip it, just modify your query to get either the requested ID, or the next highest. In fact, if you pass the direction as a variable as well, you could keep this one query:

Suppose you requested `?ID=13&next`, making this our query:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM images WHERE id >= 13 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

The direction of `<` would be determined by the presence of `&next` or `&back` in the URL:

```
$direction = isset( $_GET['back'] ) ? '<' : '>' ;
```

We're defining a default search direction of forward to our direction variable. If `&back` is present in the URL, then we will respect that and reverse the direction in the query. Otherwise, we will always look forward for the image equal to or greater than the requested ID.

And as always, check the return value of `mysql_num_rows()` for the presence of data in  your result. If your query was looking for the next image, but found nothing, you would want to inform the user they are at the end/beginning of the gallery.